# Step by step dispatch in react redux, is it right?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Let's imagine we have React Redux application. Application get data from server and append it into list (listAppend action). In fetch process application shows loading bar (requestBegin, requestEnd actions). Simple example is bellow

```
export const fetchPageNum = () => {

    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        ...
        dispatch(requestBegin())

        return fetch(url).then((response) => {

            return response.json()

        }).then((json) => {

            dispatch(pageNumSuccess(page_num))
            dispatch(listAppend(json))
            dispatch(requestEnd())

        }).catch((error) => {

            dispatch(requestEnd())
        })
    }
}
```

Is it correct to use step by step dispatch after request end?

Comment: I think yes, its perfectly correct and valid, to dispatch multiple action one after the other. Though If Its not, then would like to know why and alternative.

Comment: @agpt Yes, you are right, I want to know an alternative approach, if it is not corrent.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct and it is technically called a [thunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk)

But since you are using ES6, I would use the new `await` keyword, perhaps ending up with code looking something like this:

```
export const fetchPageNum = () => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
      dispatch(requestBegin())
      const response = await fetch(url)
      const json = await response.json()
      dispatch(pageNumSuccess(page_num))
      dispatch(listAppend(json))
    } catch (e) {
      // log error
    }
    dispatch(requestEnd())
  }
}
```

Comment: ok, i know about thunk. But is it possible to break code execution when dispatch several simple actions (without async) step by step? In other words - is sequence of dispatching several actions sync?

Comment: A sequence of dispatched actions is not _intrinsically_ synchronous or asynchronous, it depends on what you do in your actions. For example, your `listAppend` action may make an async call to a third-party api that you may wish to await before returning from `fetchPageNum`. Using the `await` keyword is great way of forcing an action-sequence to be effectively synchronous.

Comment: Each of actions `pageNumSuccess(page_num)`, `listAppend(json)`, `requestEnd()` are sync.

Comment: Thank you for answear, i will see into deep